# Games played numbers notation [MTG - Online]

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can someone explain or point me to an explanation of the notation under the 'Games' column?

What is the meaning between the order of the numbers or what do numbers 0, 1 and 2 mean? It's probably very simple and intuitive to old players but I just can't figure it out precisely.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the context in which you are seeing this "Games" column? What screen are you looking at, is there a specific tab or filter, etc.?

Comment: I figured the context is always the same. You can see the column in Tournament lobby when you're waiting for the next game or under Account > Game history - a list which contains opponent name, format and games or results column which features 'n-n' or 'n-n-n' where n is [0,2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Results" column in the Game history page shows the match win-loss record for each tournament, and you can expand each tournament to see a game win-loss-draw record for each tournament.

Comment: Perfect. I was confused by the fact that sometimes there are 2 and sometimes 3 digits. Also, in my world 1 is 'Home' win and 2 is 'Away' win :D